# call service in other service with @autowired , spring boot and i got kinda N+1 problems

Tags: java, autowired, querydsl

```
@Service("StudyHistoryService")
@Transactional
public class StudyHistoryServiceImpl implements StudyHistoryService
{
    @Autowired
    private StudyHistoryDao shDao;


    @Autowired
    private ReviewNoticeServieImpl rnService;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override 
    public ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> selectAll(long fk_ltskey) throws Exception
    {
        JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(em);
        QStudyHistoryDto qsh = QStudyHistoryDto.studyHistoryDto; 


        List<StudyHistoryDto> shDtoList = query.from(qsh)
                                  .where(qsh.ltsDto.ltskey.eq(fk_ltskey))
                                  .orderBy(qsh.cycle.asc(), qsh.dayofschedule.asc())
                                  .list(qsh);
```

When `selectAll` is working, `rnService` sends a query at the same time. Even though I made a relationship "lazy loading".

Before I autowired `rnService` they work lazy loading. But not now.

1. How can I fix this?
2. The way call service in other service I did, is that wrong?
   If so, can you teach me how to call it?

Comment: It is hard so say anything about `rnService` if you see nothing from it. And not even the end of the `selectAll()` method! Maybe the behaviour has nothing to do with `StudyHistoryServiceImpl`? You don't have an interface for `ReviewNoticeServieImpl`?

Comment: @ArneBurmeister thanks for kind reply sir. question caused by my misunderstanding.  after taking a sleep,  i got real problem. and now i gonna to find way for real problem. good luck !